Analyzing Sparse and Dense Indexes in Secondary Indexing for Orders
Created a secondary index on customer attributes for the orders, using an indirect approach with pointer buckets and an additional sparse index layer. How many blocks are needed to store this index? Assume the record pointer is 6 bytes and the block pointer is 4 bytes.
In estimating this problem, I considered that the first layer is a sparse index, the second layer is a dense index, and the third layer is buckets that point to different blocks in the data file. I’m a bit confused about understanding the dense index and sparse index.
My confusion lies in knowing that both the sparse index and dense index consist of key length and pointer length. However, I’m not clear on the details of the pointer length in this context. Specifically, in this case, do the pointers in the dense index include both the block pointer and the record pointer, or just the record pointer? Similarly, in this case, does the sparse index include both the block pointer and the record pointer, or just the block pointer?
I seek guidance from experts, thank you.
